# Quickest method of importing selected values from CSV file into MySql databse using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, csv

within my C# application, I am looking at grabbing the end of day quantities for each product from a CSV file and inputting them into a MySQL table. The issue I have is there is a separate CSV file for each day and I need to gather a years worth of data. As well as this, I only need to first 2 columns, the StockNo and the Qty, and the rest is obsolete.

I have tried using a CSVReader and that process would take far too long to complete.

Is there a quick method that will allow me to get the data I need inserted into the database?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: CSVReader reads. How do you *write*? Where is the code? If you execute a separate INSERT command for each row, you'll get bad performance no matter how fast you read. BTW MySQL doesn't have remote bulk import support.

Comment: CSVReader would read the CSV file and then I would split the line and hand pick the data I required. Then it is just a case of writing an insert command to write that data to the database. However, this method would take around 30 hours to complete which makes it impossible to use in my situation.

Comment: That "just a case of writing" is what causes the delay. If you have 1M rows and execute 1M commands, you get 1M times the latency. Batch the commands to scripts of 100 commands at a time and you get 100 times better performance. Generate an `INSERT VALUES` statement with 100 rows and you get >100 times better performance because there is less locking required.

Comment: Anyway, check the duplicate question and the MySqlBulkLoader class. It wraps a call to `LOAD DATA LOCAL` that reads data from a local file and performs a bulk load on the remote server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the method from the duplicate question worked. Thank you for linking me to the answer as I had not seen that question being asked before.

Comment: Not with *this* wording. People do ask about `bulk load`, `bulk insert`, `bulk import`.

Answer (score 0):

A really fast method is to use LOAD INFILE which works in mysql. Have a look at the mysql documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html
for example

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
    INFILE '/homeimport.csv'
    REPLACE
    INTO TABLE tabellenname
    FIELDS
            TERMINATED BY ';'
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

**Edit**

You can build a query like this to execute within c#

```
conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
string tableName = "Table1"
string query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" + fileName + "'INTO TABLE "+ tableName 
+" FIELDS TERMINATED BY '"+colSep+"' ENCLOSED BY '"+colEncap+"' ESCAPED BY 
'"+colEncap+"'LINES TERMINATED BY '"+colNewLine+"' ("+colUpFormat+");";
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: The code doesn't execute a LOCAL load. It executes on the remote server. There's no need for this anyway, the MySqlBulkLoader class does this automatically